# Unable to bind scroll function to directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a customize directive for drop down in my MEAN stack application but unable to bind a scroll function to it. Here is the directive code:

```
.directive('inputDropdown', function($parse) {

    var template = 
        '<input class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled"  placeholder="Type Name">' +
        '<div class="dropdown dropdown1">' + 
            '<div class="form-control" ng-repeat="value in selectedList | filter:ngModel | limitTo:limit">' +
                '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            list: '=',
            onSelect: '&',
            disabled:'=ngDisabled'
        },
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,mapController) {
            element.addClass('input-dropdown');

            angular.element(document.querySelector('input-dropdown')).bind('scroll', function(){ //1st way
                alert('scrolling is cool!');
              });

         //   element.scroll(function (evt) { //2nd way
          //      alert('scrolling is nama-cool!');
         //   });

            if(scope.$parent.setDirty)
            {
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            }
            scope.select = function(e, value) {
                scope.ngModel = value;
                // scope.onSelect({$event: e, value: value});
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            };
        }
    };
})
```

There are two ways in which I tried to bind the scroll function but none of them is working.

First way :

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('input-dropdown')).bind('scroll', function(){ //1st way
                alert('scrolling is cool!');
              });
```

Second way:

```
        element.scroll(function (evt) { //2nd way
            alert('scrolling is nama-cool!');
        });
```

Comment: Always create fiddle or plunker for immediate solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are missing `'.input-dropdown'` and using `.on('scroll')`

`.bind` already deprecated, you should use `.on`. See the [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

It should be

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.input-dropdown')).on('scroll', function(){ //1st way
                alert('scrolling is cool!');
              });
```

Comment: Please check again my answer. It should be `.on('scroll')`